# Is there a way to display live data using an excel file as the data source (without using any cloud service)

Tags: microsoft-excel, network-shares, data-visualization

I'm trying to figure out a way that an Excel file (which resides on a network share) can be edited by users while a separate "display" computer simply displays that data and updates it in real-time or at least near real-time (30 seconds - 1 minute delay).

The problem is that this needs to fully work on an intranet that may have no internet connection. I found a lot of solutions that are dependent a cloud component but wasn't able to find any that can do the whole thing locally.

The closest I've gotten so far is a simple shared excel workbook. That does some of what I need, but the minimum refresh time is 5 minutes. PowerBI desktop also does most of what I need but it lacks an auto refresh feature and forces you to use the cloud services for auto refresh.

Comment: Would there be any issue in creating your own web server locally for the Excel doc to communicate with?

Comment: There are likely already some web-servers on this intranet that I could leverage. I was thinking about that as a possible solution. The only downside for me would be that the skill level for someone to modify the front end rises considerably. Most users could wrap their heads around something like powerBI, but messing with some JS library is going to be way out of the league of 99% of users.

Comment: Does your company use Sharepoint? There is auto-update functionality with the Excel Web Part, so users would open the file in a Sharepoint window and it would auto refresh. Only offering as a comment, as I have not worked with this. Found some info [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-web-access-web-part-custom-properties-f08198de-c476-4e20-bea7-64248d46304e?ocmsassetID=HA010377893&CorrelationId=8cdff0ab-d50f-45e1-ae7d-214217dc8933&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). We use SP on an intranet without cloud access.

Comment: @GeorgeKendros if you end up finding a solution with Sharepoint (or anything) and no one has provided an answer, please answer your own question here! I'd be very interested to see how you solved for this, as I might be able to implement something similar and had never considered "live" sheets.

Comment: Reading up on your response, it definitely seems like it would would do exactly what's needed. Unfortunately, after checking, there's no share-point server set up anywhere on my intranet so I can't test. My solution is just going to be used shared excel files and deal with the 5 minute delay (unfortunately).